# React Native Set State not a function, in a for each loop not sure about binding?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following code, on my component mount but I'm getting set state is not a function error which I know is a binding issue but I'm not where I should be doing the binding?

```
const selectedTag = this.props.tag;

        // Checks to see if this should be selected
        let checkSelected = function(arr, val) {
            _(arr).each(function(value) {
                if (value == val) {
                    this.setState({checked: true})
                }
            });
        };
        checkSelected(this.props.selectedTags, selectedTag)
        console.log(this.state.checked)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **arrow function** to keep the scope of `this` intact :

```
 let checkSelected =(arr, val) =>  {
        _(arr).each((value) =>  {
            if (value == val) {
                this.setState({checked: true})
            }
        });
    };
```

and NOT  :

```
 let checkSelected = function(arr, val) {
        _(arr).each(function(value) {
            if (value == val) {
                this.setState({checked: true})
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: replace all functions by arrow functions.

Comment: Try now @AlmogKoren.

Comment: I updated my answe. Indeed, I gave you an example how to convert a function to an arrow function and you should go to all callbacks and convert them as arrow functions... But since you didn't get my point, I did it for you and I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes I got it, no errors now but the set state is always false, it's not setting it to true even though there is a match

Comment: If so , it means no `val` equals `value`  since setState is called inside `if` block.

Comment: Anyway, according to your question details , I assume the issue is resolved. I recommend to resolve the question and open new question with new  issue but after doing troubleshooting.

Comment: If it's not console logging correctly it's because setState is async, you if you want to check with console log, you want to put it as a callback in setState. `this.setState({checked: true}, () => console.log(this.state.checked)`

Comment: That's why I recommended him to open new issue where we can explain signature of setState  : (obj), (obj, callback) , (callback) and (callback, callback). If your state relies on previous state, the first agrument should be a callback, if you have code rely on the next state, the second argument should be a callback , otherwise the rest.  BTW, you can use async await and  get rid off second callback. @MattAft you are welcome  to check our answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47062058/747579

Answer (score 0):

Try declare global this outside the each func and use it

```
var _this = this;  // Reference 

let checkSelected = function(arr, val) {
        _(arr).each(function(value) {
            if (value == val) {
                _this.setState({checked: true})
            }
        });
  };
```

Comment: Its going thru the if, there is a match